# Array в конце foreach

Tags: массивы, php, парсер, foreach

Есть код парсера:

```
    <?php

 $url = file_get_contents("http://api.dotaprj.me/jd/matches/v130/api.json");

 $content = json_decode($url,true); 
  foreach($content as $key => $subarray) {

    if($key != 'eventSoon'){
        continue;
    }

    echo '<table style="font-size: 10px;">  ';

    foreach($subarray as $item){
        echo $item;
    }
    echo '</table>';
  } 
     ?>
```

После выведенных значений выводит надпись Array, при чем только в мадулях шаблона (использую Joomla)

Пример - http://dota2.gamestreamtv.ru/ справа блок РАСПИСАНИЕ ИГР!

Помогите решить!
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: вполне возможно, что  $item - это массив, поэтому и выводит Array. Напишите вместо echo $item; - print_r($item);

Comment: Сам код ничего "лишнего" не выводит.

Попробуйте в этом коде изменить имя переменной `$content` на какое-нибудь `$content100500` - вдруг поможет.

А еще лучше - преобразуйте код в функцию: наверняка проблема с областью видимости.

Comment: Изменение $content  помогло спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function apiDotapiParser($event = 'eventSoon', $url = 'http://api.dotaprj.me/jd/matches/v130/api.json')
{
    $table = '';
    $content = @file_get_contents($url);
    if ($content) {
        $content = json_decode($content, true);
        if (isset($content[$event]) && is_array($content[$event])) {
            $table = implode($content[$event], '');
        }
    }
    return $table;
    }

echo '<table style="font-size: 10px;">' . apiDotapiParser() . '</table>';
```

Тот же результат с более оптимальным подходом.